# ClickOnce: How to deploy two copies of the same assembly on different locations in the application deployment?

Tags: .net, clickonce

We have an 'offline' Windows application that wraps an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) application in an Internet Explorer control within a Windows form. Therefore we have a sub-tree in the application folder that is the entire online/web application, and this is launched and run within the wrapping offline application EXE file.

This has resulted in some assemblies being present as both a direct reference from the offline application EXE file and also part of the online application sub-folder. This works fine when deploying the application by doing a manual copy of the entire application folder tree. However, a ClickOnce deployment fails at installation time when validating the ClickOnce application manifest - I've honed in on the duplicate assemblies as the problem, if I remove these assemblies from the online application sub-tree (leaving just one copy of each in the root folder) and rebuild/sign the application manifest without them then the validation succeeds and the application is installed - but without the assemblies I removed of course.

**=== UPDATE ===**

A new version of mage.exe was provided for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4 (the newer copy is part of Windows SDK v7.1 - in the NETFX 4.0 Tools folder), and the new version exhibits different behaviour for duplicate assemblies.

In the application manifest created by [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) v3.x the duplicates are listed using 'file' elements as follows:

```
  <file name="foo.dll" size="123456">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>JFifxtn6vhCtaiom4tzJ+pcgqT0=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>
```

and warnings of the following form are generated:

> **Warning MSB3178: Assembly'\AppFiles\fooApp_2.9.186.3\foo.dll' is incorrectly specified as a file.**

In fact both duplicate files are listed like this, that is, neither is listed as a 'dependentAssembly', which is clearly wrong.

However, Mage v4 creates a 'dependentAssembly' entry for both files and warning of the form:

> **Warning MSB3112: Two or more assemblies have the same identity 'foo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789012345, ProcessorArchitecture=msil'.**

The two entries are identical except for the path (defined on the 'codebase' attribute), but at installation time the ClickOnce installer fails if a deployment contains such entries with a vague error:

> **the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to either rename any one of them and use. Also try with different versions and publickey token for each assembly